# Redmine on Heroku - undefined method 'has_key?' for nil:NilClass @ email.rake:170

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redmine

I'm trying to run Redmine on Heroku. Redmine returns a 500 error, presumably because my rake db:migrate fails:

> at /app/lib/tasks/email.rake:170
>   rake aborted!
>   undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass

The Heroku stack is bamboo-ree-1.8.7. Here's my Gemfile:

```
source :gemcutter

gem 'i18n', '0.4.2'
gem 'rails', '2.3.11'
gem 'coderay', '0.9.7'
gem 'rack', '1.1.1'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
gem 'rubytree'
```

How do I get `heroku rake db:migrate` to work?

Answer (score 2):

you should lock your rubytree gem to 0.5.2

try this

```
gem "rubytree", "0.5.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by doing two things.

First, I followed some suggestions from http://bayleshanks.com/tips-computer-programming-redmineOnHeroku (specifically I added the suggested line to config/environment.rb and created a blank file called public/plugin_assets/README).

Second, I modified the Gemfile to specify rubytree version 0.6.2, ran bundle install, re-committed the Gemfile.lock into git, and pushed to Heroku.

I'm not sure the earlier steps were necessary, but the database migration finally worked and Redmine is now running.

Answer (score 0):

+1, the above worked for me as well, after satisfying a number of other dependency problems.  Ideally, someone should write up a good HOWTO on deploying Heroku, though Ruby/Rails is such a moving target, it would likely only be accurate for a few minutes.